# Making API from Python docstrings written in PEP8

Tags: python, python-sphinx, docstring

I've written a code in Python. I tried to be follow common guidelines about writing helpful comments at the beginnings of functions. My style is PEP8, e.g.

```
def __init__(self, f_name=None, list_=None, cut_list=None, n_events=None, description=None):
        """
        Parse an LHCO or ROOT file into a list of Event objects.

        It is possible to initialize an Events class without a LHCO file,
        and later append events to the list.

        Arguments:
        f_name -- Name of an LHCO or ROOT file, including path
        list_ -- A list for initalizing Events
        cut_list -- Cuts applied to events and their acceptance
        n_events -- Number of events to read from LHCO file
        description -- Information about events
        """
```

I want to automatically generate a helpful API from my code. I've found a few options and was looking at Sphinx in particular. It seemed to do what I wanted (though I struggled to make it generate an API, rather than a manual for my program). The drawback, however, was that it has it's own expected style for docstrings:

```
"""
:param x: My parameter
:type x: Its type
"""
```

Is it really best for me to rewrite all my docstrings with this syntax? They produce a nice API, but I don't like them in the code, and it'll be time consuming if it turns out to be a bad idea. What is standard, best practice? Should I convert? If so, can something do it automatically for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Sphinx default format for docstrings is really quite powerful and is definitely worth the time if you want to generate clean API documentation and if you need to review your own code in months, years. So yes, it is a good idea.

If you don't like the default Sphinx-ReST syntax, you could try writing your docstrings [the way Numpy do](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/HOWTO_DOCUMENT.rst.txt), e.g.:

```
def func(arg1, arg2):
    """Summary line.

    Extended description of function.

    Parameters
    ----------
    arg1 : int
        Description of arg1
    arg2 : str
        Description of arg2

    Returns
    -------
    bool
        Description of return value

    """
    return True
```

There's a Sphinx extension ([Napoleon](https://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)) which allows Sphinx to parse this style (or the Google style, which is even simpler).

Answer (score 1):

I think that the Sphinx syntax is pretty lightweight (be glad it's not Javadoc) so in terms of pretty raw code it's not a serious disadvantage.

My IDE, PyCharm, automatically creates skeletons in the Sphinx style when I add a docstring to a function. So there's some developers who know a thing or two about Python (and who also like to push for PEP8 style in other areas a lot) and recommend Sphinx. PyCharm even has a type hinting system used for inference and type checking, which starts by checking the declarations in the docstring.

Here's a regex you can use to make the conversion automatically. Replace

```
^(\s+)(\w+) -- (.+)$
```

with

```
$1:param $2: $3\n$1:type $2:
```

where `$n` represents the nth group. Of course you will need to fill out the type yourself.